# Real-time stat mysql in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have about 300+ tables to count in mysql every 10 seconds. Each table correspond each stat table

Example :

```
def pool_func(pool, table_name):
    for name in table_name:
        pool.add(gevent.spawn(BaseStat(table_name=name).run))
    pool.join()
```

BaseStat.run :(I use crontab to deploy, just run every minute)

*self.frequency = 10*

```
def run(self):
    try:
        if self.table_name is None:
            raise Exception("You should set BaseStat table_name")
        self.stat_table_name = self.table_name + self.table_stat_suffix

        start = 0
        self._run_stat()
        while start < 60:
            start += self.frequency
            gevent.sleep(self.frequency)
            self.start_time, self.end_time = self._get_time(self.start_time, self.end_time)
            self._run_stat()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.get("stat-log").error("[%s] : %s" % (self.table_name, util.error_msg()))
```

When the amount of table small it can work well but now it at least 2 minutes delay.Total time running `pool_func` about 578.056058168 seconds

Comment: What is the value of `self.frequency`?

Comment: self.frequency is 10 thanks @KlausD.